# C - fclose() triggers a breakpoint

Tags: c, breakpoints, stdio, fclose

I'm writing a function (`*rwObjects()`) that will read a formatted file and save it's strings, one object at a time. Unfortunately, it's for my studies which have a restriction - stdio.h, stdlib.h and string.h is practically all I can use.

Here's the problem: whenever I run the code, when it gets to the `fclose(input)`, VS17 says my project's triggered a breakpoint, and then opens a tab that says "wntdll.pdb not loaded" or something.

The question is: how do I not trigger the breakpoint and close the file properly? Or, if the problem isn't in the file, where is it?

Code (C):

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define cnCOUNTRY_LENGTH 3
#define cnOBJECT_NAME_LENGTH 30
#define cnOBJECT_MAX 1000

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//--Поле объекта objectType--
//Country (0)       - строка названия страны
//ObjectName (1)    - строка названия объекта
//Square (2)        - площадь объекта
//Error (3)         - ошибка в содержании строки
typedef enum IOOptions {Country, ObjectName, Square, Error} IOType;

//--Тип обрабатываемых объектов--
//char Country      - строка названия страны
//char ObjectName   - строка названия объекта
//int Square        - площадь объекта
typedef struct object {
    char Country[cnCOUNTRY_LENGTH];
    char ObjectName[cnOBJECT_NAME_LENGTH];
    int Square;
} objectType;

//--Копирование текущего элемента строки objects.txt--
//strMod            - Строка, в которую идёт копирование
//strPos            - Позиция в считываемой строке
//strBlueprint      - Строка, из которой идёт копирование
//writeType         - Поле объекта objectType. При "Country" - переводит вводимые символы в верхний регистр ('a' -> 'A' и т.д.)
void copyInputStr(char *strMod, int *strPos, char *strBlueprint, IOType writeType) {
    for (*strPos; *strBlueprint != ' ' && *strBlueprint != '\n' && *strBlueprint != NULL; *strPos = *strPos + 1) {
        *strMod = *strBlueprint;
        if (writeType == Country) toupper(*strMod);
        strBlueprint++; strMod++;
    }
}

//--Запись текущего элемента строки objects.txt в текущий объект--
//strInput          - Строка, из которой идёт запись
//objectOutput      - Объект, в который идёт запись
//writeType         - Поле объекта, в которое идёт запись
void writeObject(char *strInput, objectType *objectOutput, IOType writeType) {
    if (writeType == Country)
        strcpy(objectOutput->Country, strInput);
    else if (writeType == ObjectName)
        strcpy(objectOutput->ObjectName, strInput);
    else if (writeType == Square)
        objectOutput->Square = atoi(strInput);
    else printf("Error 1. Invalid parameters");
}

//--Чтение objects.txt и запись в массив objectType--
//Возвращает указатель на первый элемент массива объектов
objectType *rwObjects() {
    FILE *input = fopen("objects.txt", "r");
    char objectQttStr[4], objectStr[38];
    fgets(objectQttStr, 4, input);
    objectType *objectList = (objectType *)malloc(atoi(objectQttStr)), *currentObject = objectList;
    currentObject = (objectType *)malloc(atoi(objectQttStr));
    for (int i = 0; i < atoi(objectQttStr); i++) {
        fgets(objectStr, 38, input);
        IOType inputType = Country;
        for (int j = 0; objectStr[j] != NULL && objectStr[j] != '\n'; j++) {
            char strBuf[cnOBJECT_NAME_LENGTH];
            memset(&strBuf, 0, sizeof(strBuf));

            copyInputStr(&strBuf, &j, &objectStr[j], inputType);

            writeObject(&strBuf, currentObject, inputType);

            inputType++; 
        }
        currentObject++;
    }
    fclose(input);         //this is where it happens
    return objectList;
}

void main() {
    objectType *objectList = rwObjects();
    printf("");
}
```

This is one confusing program, but I've found no other way to conform the bloody rules, so let's put the coding style aside, shall we?

Also, I know that should it run successfully, nothing would happen - that is by design. It's not finished yet.

EDIT: Don't worry about validity of input data. All the input data formatting is explicitly stated in the task, ergo no checks are reqired. Still, for the curious, here it is:

objects.txt:

```
3
USA WelfareArrangement 120
Rus PoiskZemli 30
usa asdfEstate 1
```

EDIT 2: The moment I stopped using malloc, everything was fine. The question is - why exactly was it such a problem, and how would I create an array of the exact size I need, instead of creating max size evey time, if not with malloc?

Comment: I imagine you have a breakpoint set somewhere, perhaps inside the standard library code.  Is there a way in VS17 to view/list all breakpoints?

Comment: `objectStr[j] != NULL` looks like code is comparing a `char` to a pointer.  Recommend `objectStr[j] != '\0'` instead.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Tried. Only lists the breakpoints in my project, not in the outside files. If there are any, I wasn't the one who put them there.
And no, it doesn't work if I get rid of all my breakpoints.

Comment: I wonder if there's a write out of bounds corrupting `input`, maybe in `copyInputStr`?

Comment: Your memory allocations make no sense. You seem to be allocating an array of structures, but you only give them one byte each. Then you assign a current pointer, which you then overwrite with a new useless allocation.

Comment: Code should check the return value of `fgets(objectStr, 38, input);`.

Comment: Whatever warning level you're using, it isn't high enough. [A sample of warnings from clang here](https://pastebin.com/CVQYXAqe).

Comment: Post your sample input.  `fgets(objectQttStr, 4, input);` looks quite small for an integer.

Comment: I think you're hitting an assert or a VS error, not a breakpoint.  I don't use VS, so I can't look further, but I suspect that you've corrupted your input pointer somehow and fclose is complaining.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker How do I assign them one byte? I thought I assign them just enough to contain objectQttStr number of objectType structures. And VS seems to agree, judging by the control values window.

Comment: I'm assuming objQttStr means something like "object quantity"? It's passed to malloc directly. malloc's argument is a number of bytes, not a number of objects. Perhaps you meant to use calloc?

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker objQttStr is passed wrapped in atoi(). So the value is passed.
Honestly, I'm not quite sure how malloc works, but the way I see it, it allocates (type *) malloc (amount), which means it allocates exactly type times amount memory. At least it's true for any other type. Maybe using a structure is the problem.

Comment: Nope. Malloc allocates bytes, period. You need to do that multiplication yourself, or else you'll be shitting all over unallocated memory and causing faults...hey...

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker Interesting. So the things taught to us in our university are lies. I'll try to avoid allocating weird things and see if it works. Also, c can burn in hell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First problem:

```
objectType *objectList = (objectType *)malloc(atoi(objectQttStr)), *currentObject = objectList;
currentObject = (objectType *)malloc(atoi(objectQttStr));
```

The `malloc` function allocates a given number of bytes.  So if you have 5 objects, you only allocate 5 bytes.  That's not enough for your structs.  This results in you writing past the end of allocated memory which invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

If you want it to allocate space for a specific number of objects, you need to multiply by the object size:

```
objectType *objectList = malloc(sizeof(*objectList)*atoi(objectQttStr));
```

Also, [don't cast the return value of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

You also assign `currentObject` to the same value as `objectList` but then overwrite it with a separate memory allocation.  So get rid of the second `malloc`.

Second problem:

```
        memset(&strBuf, 0, sizeof(strBuf));

        copyInputStr(&strBuf, &j, &objectStr[j], inputType);

        writeObject(&strBuf, currentObject, inputType);
```

Your `copyInputStr` and `writeObject` function expect a `char *`, but you pass in the address of the `strBuf` array which has type `char (*)[30]`.  Get rid of the address-of operator here:

```
        memset(strBuf, 0, sizeof(strBuf));

        copyInputStr(strBuf, &j, &objectStr[j], inputType);

        writeObject(strBuf, currentObject, inputType);
```

Third problem:

```
void copyInputStr(char *strMod, int *strPos, char *strBlueprint, IOType writeType) {
    for (*strPos; *strBlueprint != ' ' && *strBlueprint != '\n' && *strBlueprint != NULL; *strPos = *strPos + 1) {
        *strMod = *strBlueprint;
        if (writeType == Country) toupper(*strMod);
        strBlueprint++; strMod++;
    }
}
```

When you copy the characters in `strMod`, you're not adding a null byte at the end.  A string in C is a null-terminated array of characters, so what you end up with is not a string but just an array of characters.  When you later call `strcpy` on this array, the function doesn't find a null byte so it keeps reading until it does.  This causes the function to read uninitialized bytes and/or read past the end of the array, which again invokes undefined behavior.

Add the null terminating byte after the loop.  Also, the result of the `toupper` function isn't assigned to anything, so it does nothing.  You need to assign it back to `*strMod`:

```
void copyInputStr(char *strMod, int *strPos, char *strBlueprint, IOType writeType) {
    for (*strPos; *strBlueprint != ' ' && *strBlueprint != '\n' && *strBlueprint != NULL; *strPos = *strPos + 1) {
        *strMod = *strBlueprint;
        if (writeType == Country) *strMod = toupper(*strMod);
        strBlueprint++; strMod++;
    }
    *strMod = 0;
}
```

Comment: You, sir, are amazing. You didn't only answer my question in the most possible depth, you also solved a few problems I've been at myself (even though I've figured them out meanwhile). You deserve infinite praise.